# Cassandra cluster key in query vs multiple query efficiency

Tags: cassandra

Is the `in` operator on the cluster key more efficient than multiple equality queries?

```
select * from table where primaryKey1 = 1 and primaryKey2 = 2 and clusterKey in (1,2)
```

vs.  2 queries.

```
select * from table where primaryKey1 = 1 and primaryKey2 = 2 and clusterKey = 1 

select * from table where primaryKey1 = 1 and primaryKey2 = 2 and clusterKey = 2
```

Comment: IMHO, as clustering key is used for ordering data in partition, the performance for above queries will be same regardless of which approach we used to search for particular clustering key (e.g. hash-based, binary search, etc) and we already know which partition to look at based on primary key critertia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how much values you are going to put inside **IN** operator. In terms of efficiency, both will take around the same time to return resultSet. But if your values are going to be larger, it's a good practice to use multiple queries instead of using **IN** operator.

This is due to the distributed node structure of Cassandra when you are using a single query with **IN** keyword, the request/response will be handled by only one node. Moreover, if something goes wrong Cassandra will run the whole query again from scratch and retrieved results won't be stored.

You can use Async queries in Java or python which will run multiple queries as a batch process. I will allow request/response to go through multiple nodes and if a single query fails it can retry again for only that specific query.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, name text);

SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (
    e6af74a8-4711-4609-a94f-2cbfab9695e5,
    281336f4-2a52-4535-847c-11a4d3682ec1,
    c32b8d37-89bd-4dfe-a7d5-5f0258692d05
);
```

This is not necessarily optimal: this query will be sent to a coordinator node, which will then have to query replicas for each partition key. Considering that we have a smart [token-aware](https://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html) driver, it would be more efficient to send an individual query for each partition key (SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?), which would reach the right replica directly. Then all that's left is to collate the results client-side.

```
Future<List<ResultSet>> future = ResultSets.queryAllAsList(session, 
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?",UUID.fromString("e6af74a8-4711-
4609-a94f-2cbfab9695e5"), UUID.fromString("281336f4-2a52-4535-847c-
11a4d3682ec1"));
for (ResultSet rs : future.get()) {
    process the result set    
}
```

For more clarification please read links below:
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries